# Direction of asymptote to electric field line

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

For two positive point charges in space separated by some finite distance, the electric field lines we observe look like this:

[image]

(for point $P$ being the neutral point, the line shown in red is asymptotic to the field line emerging from a charged point $q_{_1}$ at an angle $\alpha$)

Suppose we have 2 positive charges $q_{_1}$ and $q_{_2}$. If an electric field line emerges from $q_{_1}$ at an angle $\alpha$ from the line joining charges $q_{_1}$ and $q_{_2}$, is there a way we can derive the slope of asymptote to the given field line?

In simple words, can we derive a relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

---

**Edit**

I've been thinking that if somehow we can count the number of field lines emitted in the conical region, having semi vertical angle equal to $\beta$ and with its vertex at $P$, that do not go out of the curved surface area of the cone (hence I mean, measuring the flux through the base of the cone); we can then equate this with the number of field lines emitted from charge $q_{\small{1}}$ within the solid angle $ \Omega= 2\pi\left(1- \cos(\alpha)\right)$. Which is, in magnitude, equal to $\varphi=\frac{q_{\small{1}}}{2\varepsilon_0}\left(1-cos\alpha\right)$.

Hence my question shrinks to:

- How to calculate the number of field lines emitted inside the solid angle $2\pi\left(1-\cos\beta\right)$ subtended at point $P$?

Comment: Naïvely, I would expect that asymptotically the field would be that of a point charge with magnitude $q_1 + q_2$, and so you could equate the flux that way.  If I didn't have a bunch of grades to submit I'd try to work up an answer along these lines.

Comment: You will need to start by defining the line density in lines/coulomb. I like Michael's idea.

Comment: In practice, it becomes very difficult to determine the angle between two field lines leaving the surface of a sphere in three dimensions.  I'm not even certain that it is possible to uniformly distribute a given  number of lines around the surface of a sphere.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I've thought of doing the same, or atleast what I interpret your suggestion that, asymptotic lines to be assumed as the field lines of combined charge $q_1 + q_2$, placed at point P. But I'm concerned that if the point P can be assumed to be at effective charge of $q_1+q_2$, why is the number of field lines zero there, instead of being maximum?

Comment: The fields from the two positive charges are in opposite directions at point P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments regarding the conservation of electric flux in [this previous answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/598218/8563) apply equally well here, with the minor change that the second angle corresponds to the combined charges here: the flux calculation happens, asymptotically, at infinity, where the electric field looks like that of a point charge with the combined charge, located at the center of charge (as defined [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/592728/8563)), plus a quadrupole correction which is negligible at infinity.

As such, the correct relationship between the two angles, as you have defined them, is
$$
(1-\cos(\alpha))q_1 = (1-\cos(\beta))(q_1+q_2).
$$

Comment: @SteelCubes The argumentation in this answer is sufficient to deduce that.

Comment: I finally understand it now. Thanks

Comment: Nice answer.  One minor nitpick, though:  I don't think that the center of charge is the same thing as the OP's "neutral point" $P$, which (I assume) is the point where $\vec{E}$ vanishes.  Taking into account this difference would add a dipole correction as well. I don't think it really matters in the end, though, since we're measuring the angle $\beta$ at infinity, and the dipole correction can be neglected there as well.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The center of charge is indeed distinct from the 'neutral point'. (At the latter you have ${q_1}/{r_1^2} = {q_1}/{r_2^2}$ in the obvious notation; at the former you have $q_1r_1=q_2r_2$.) The correct starting point for the asymptotes is the COC, which can be easily verified numerically (for future reference: `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2S2k.png"]`). The dipole correction clearly matters in finding the origin for the streamlines (...though I'm not sure I see a fully rigorous argument for this).

Comment: @SteelCubes The Mathematica notebook in the previous comment (just run the code block on an empty cell) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert ... but yes, I agree $-$ the starting point is irrelevant when determining the angle of the asymptote, as that is only evaluated at infinity.

Comment: Whats the dipole correction referred here?

Comment: @Orion_Pax The dipole term in the multipolar expansion of the field for large $r$. If you want more details, ask separately.

Comment: I was asking a similar problem but the thread was closed , i was asking for the proof of q1 +q2 and where its placed so as to find flux of asymptote part . Can u tell in there @Emilio_Pisanty using electric field lines ?

Comment: And how one can view the code above if one has not a subscription to wolfram mathematica?

Comment: And yeah i got the correction part

Comment: @Orion_Pax The code linked above can only be accessed using Mathematica. Without it, you can code your own, using your platform of choice; it is fairly straightforward. I'm uninterested in further back-and-forth, though.

Comment: Yeah its ok @Emilio_Pisanty I was asking a similar problem but the thread was closed , i was asking for the proof of q1 +q2 and where its placed so as to find flux of asymptote part . Can u tell the proof of this if possible? using electric field lines

Answer (score 0):

Going with Michael's idea and noting that the field line of interest in your sketch is actually the resultant field, then at very large distances the asymptote becomes a tangent to a radial resultant from a net charge q = $q_1$ + $q_2$.  Then the number you are looking will be the total number of lines times the fraction of a sphere occupied by the given solid angle;  N = (lines/coulomb)q[Ω/(4π)].

Comment: I'm not quite able to get your words. Firstly, $\Omega=2\pi(1-\cos\alpha)$. But the field lines emitted at angle $\alpha$ are originated form $q_1$ solely, with or without presence of external influence. So, I can't see why you think of multiplying "q" with $\frac{\Omega}{4\pi}$. Secondly, I still am confused about $\beta$

Comment: The field lines shown on the sketch represent the resultant which you get after taking the vector sum of the fields from the two charges. Remember, the field lines from a single spherical charge do not bend. Now that I think about it, β is an  independent variable which determines the solid angle. The direction of the field line at a large distance does not depend on α; only on β.