# Connection between Möbius transformation and equipotential lines in 2D electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, vector-fields, complex-numbers

Recently, while reading about the [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), I found this picture:

[image]

As written on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), this represents an hyperbolic Möbius transformation. Does this remind you of anything?

Personally, when I look at the blue lines in this picture, I think equipotential lines of a charge dipole:

[image]

The red lines in the first picture also seem to correspond to the field lines in the second one. I just learned about the existence of Möbius transformations, so unfortunately I'm not sure what the red and blue lines are supposed to represent exactly.

I know that there is a connection between 2D electrostatics and complex numbers: after all, complex number are somehow similar to (although more general than) 2D vectors.

However, now I'm wondering: what is the exact connection, if it exists, between Möbius transformations and equipotential lines in 2D electrostatics?

Comment: The equipotential lines and field lines of a dipole are not circles, see my answer here : [Trajectory of electric field lines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667475/trajectory-of-electric-field-lines/668506#668506).

Comment: The transformation you refer to is not Möbius but a kind of conformal transformation known as Schwarz-Christoffel transformation (the method was first published by Schwarz and
Christoffel independently of each other). Generally this transformation opens out the interior of a polygon in the $\:z-$ plane to the upper half of the $\:w-$plane. In our case of Collinear Source and Sink it's similar to Möbius
\begin{equation}
z=\ln\dfrac{w-a}{w+a}
\tag{a}\label{a}
\end{equation}

Comment: Reference : *$''$ Conformal Transformations in Electrical Engineering $''$* by William John Gibbs ($\ne$ JOSIAH WILLARD GIBBS), CHAPTER 7, $\S$ Collinear Source and Sink.

Comment: Page [83](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn3WN.jpg) , page [84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX964.jpg), page [85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd2XE.jpg), page [86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzPbS.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @Frobenius. I know that equipotential lines of a dipole are not circles. Still, I find the similarity to be remarkable. It seems to me that your comment on the Schwerz-Christoffel transformation could maybe be expanded into an answer?