# Closed surface present in a electric field, no charge inside then net flux is zero. So what does that tell?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

It means like water entering and whole water coming out so net flux is zero, I know that but so what? Isn't that obvious? and even if it is not what does that tell about electric field and it's properties or what does that tell about surface and what is use of this?

Is there in pre-existing fact that would have been proved wrong if it wasn't so?

Simply: tell me why this is so and why this has to be true what would have happen if it wasn't zero.

I might sound frustrated, actually I am sorry for that.

Comment: Sounds like you want to know the usefulness (applications) of Gauss' law. See  last slide of http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gaulaw.html

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Trajectory of electric field lines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667475/trajectory-of-electric-field-lines/668506#668506). **(2)** [Angle of electric field lines leaving a positive charge and entering a negative charge in dipole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284885/angle-of-electric-field-lines-leaving-a-postive-charge-and-entering-a-negative-c).

Answer (score 1):

In the solution to a problem recently discussed on this site, this aspect of Gauss' law was used to derive the equation for the path of a field line produced by an electric dipole. Simple ideas can often be useful.